# How can I tell if there's a living snail in the shell, without picking it up?

Tags: animals, animal-behaviour, beach

When I go to the beach, I love to look at sea shells. I never take them with me because they're vital to the eco-system. I just gently pick them up, have a close look and sometimes take pictures, then put them back where they were.

It's very important to me not to bother any animals. In the case of certain mollusks like clams and mussels, a closed shell is an indication of life. Barnacles, seaweed and a variety of other living things are easily spotted.

Snail shells are beautiful, varied and interesting, but it's not always easy to tell if there's a live snail inside, especially because they can go so far in that you can't see them.

According to [Snail Facts](http://www.snailfacts.net/sea_snails/sea_snails.html),

> The snail can protect itself easily by withdrawing its body behind the operculum that works like a trap door.

Without seeing movement or evidence of a body, how can I tell just from looking at the shell if it contains a living snail that needs to be left undisturbed?

Comment: Do you not want to pick up a live snail because you are concerned about hurting it, or just on principle of not disturbing it? I ask because I've picked up (land) snails as a kid, and while they retracted into their shells, they did not seem harmed and continued on their way a few minutes after I put them back. But, I'm not sure if that is in line with what you're asking. (Also I have no idea if it's different for sea snails, which it seems you are asking about.)

Comment: @whrrgarbl  I'd prefer not to scare it at all, because that's what makes it hide, but ultimately I want to make sure not to damage it or its home. Thanks for sharing your experience, which shows that even if they momentarily hide, they can be fine and able to wander away once they feel secure. My question is about sea snails because it relates to beach-combing. I didn't think about land snails, and don't know if they're different. I should probably research that!

Comment: Another reason this could be important, is that disturbing the wrong living snail could go worse for you than the snail.  Beach combers should ensure that they are able to correctly identify a [cone snail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_snail).  If touching one, do so *only* with a ten pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to pick one up without a live snail inside, I would say finding one on dry sand without a trail that looks like it has been there a while. The signs of that would be, being flipped upside down and having small debris like sand or dirt on top of it.

This  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enPACKaL4ZQ) shows a sea snail moving at a snail's pace leaving a trail behind it.

If you were to find some empty shells, then it would give you an idea of how much they weigh empty and then if you ever did pick up a live one, you should be able to tell the difference and put it down right away.